# Condorcet winner and pluralism by 51%

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, voting-theory

Is it possible for the winner by pluralism to not be the Condorcer winner, if the winner by pluralism wins by 51%? This assumes 3 or more candidates. Also this assumes a rank and or preferential voting system

By 51% I am including rounding, so if you received 50.5% or higher.

Comment: do you also assume that each voter can vote one person?

Comment: Well condorcet voting implies a rank or preferential voting system. As in will is my first choice, terry second, maria third and so on.

Comment: Ok, then I will rethink it, ignore my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If people vote reflecting their preferences (i.e. voting for their first preference candidate) then somebody who gets over 50% of votes would be the Condorcet candidate.

There are other issues: in particular simple plurality systems may discourage some voters from voting for their first preference candidate, and if this happens, then somebody who gets over 50% of votes might not be the Condorcet candidate.

Suppose the distribution of preferences were in three groups:

```
Voters 1st 2nd 3rd
====== === === ===
 49     A   C   B
 48     B   C   A
  3     C   B   A
```

The third group might decide to vote for B to stop A from winning (C cannot win a plurality election without votes from the first or second groups), so B might get 51% even though C would be the Condorcet candidate.

Comment: I didn't think of that! Insincere voting!! Thank you!